# UNICODE Names From Character

Tags: unicode, mfc, character

Can anyone tell me how to get the Unicode name of a character in MFC. 
e.g. -

Character - Name
Z - LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
[ - LEFT SQUARE BRACKET

etc.
Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible (unless you hack charmap.exe). I solved the problem by adding a text-file resource to my application, containing all these names. You can download my file from http://privat.rejbrand.se/NamesListParsed.txt.

Comment: That file was very useful to me. I can't believe it was still there after 10 years :-)

Comment: @Patrick: My policy is that if I publish a URL, it should always remain valid (at least for as long as I am alive!).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Great resource! What is the source of your name list? What is the official repository of these names? Is it https://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html?

Comment: @Basj: I use https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/. Specifically, https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt and its siblings.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRejbrand! this is the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158620/official-repository-of-unicode-character-names! Feel free to post it.