# Official repository of Unicode character names

Tags: python, string, unicode

There are a few ways to get the list of all Unicode characters' names: for example using Python module [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html), as explained in [List of unicode character names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302766/list-of-unicode-character-names), or using the website: https://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html but here it's incomplete, and you have to open and parse PDF to find the names.

**But what is the official source / repository of all Unicode character names?** (such that if a new character is added, the list is updated, so I'm looking for the initial source for these names, in a machine readable format).

I'm looking for a list with just `code point` and `name`, in CSV or any other format:

```
code   character name
...
0102   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE
0103   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH BREVE
...
```

Comment: What has this to do with "python", "string" and "utf-8"?

Comment: @AmigoJack I initially wanted to use `unicodedata` https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html, as mentioned in the question, but you're right this aspect is secondary.

Comment: How about editing your question so `unicodedata` links to Python (because it can mean [something different](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L1999/UnicodeData.html)) and removing the other two tags? I came here for "utf-8" just to find out the encoding is nowhere involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official source for the actual character data (which includes the character names and many, many other details) is [the Unicode Character Database](https://unicode.org/ucd/).

The latest version of the data files can be accessed via http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/.

Names specifically can be found in [the files `NamesList.txt`](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt). The format of that file is [described here](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.html).

This is the list in CSV format: https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt

Comment: The official names are in `UnicodeData.txt`, and much easier to parse. OTOH your files contain other names (from `NameAliases.txt`) which are all "official" and in same namespace.

Comment: This CSV file contains 34627 lines. Yet, Wikipedia claims there are 144697 characters in Unicode. It's also backed by official page - https://www.unicode.org/versions/stats/charcountv14_0.html

Comment: @Ginden UnicodeData.txt doesn't include the "Unihan" CJK data for Chinese, Japanese & Korean characters. This is deployed separately in [Unihan.zip](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Unihan.zip).

Comment: @moon This explains disrepancy, but there are **39493** characters in "Alphabetics, Symbols". `39493-34627 = 4866`